# GraphQL - Select different fields of a returned list per item

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

Lets say i have the following query:

```
query getBooksQuery($userId: String) {
  getBooks(userId: $userId) {
    id
    description
    image
    user {
      email
      firstName
      lastName
      image
    }
  }
}
```

Imagine i have to show a list with books of a user and display the author details above the list. Since I'm querying with a `userId`, i know that all books belong to the same user.
So, i would not like to get for each book of the list the same user details, but get them only once in the response.
Is there any way to declare that i want these info only for the first book i.e.?

Or is it the only way to have two objects in the response, like:

```
query getBooksQuery($userId: String) {
  getBooks(userId: $userId) {
    books {
      id
      description
      image
    }
    user {
      email
      firstName
      lastName
      image
    } 
  }
}
```

Unfortunately with the second solution, even if its clearer at this point, will require server-side work to support this custom query. So i was thinking if it is still feasible using the current api.
(Also ofc i can do two requests, one for the user and one for the books, but meh...)

I'm using Apollo without relay, but I'm experimenting at this point, so if not feasible in Apollo but feasible otherwise I'm still interested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same param for 2 'subqueries' in one request

```
query getBooksQuery($userId: String) {
  getBooks(userId: $userId) {
    books {
      id
      description
      image
    }
  }
  getUsers(userId: $userId) {
    user {
      email
      firstName
      lastName
      image
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: This way of combination of different resolvers is a life changer! unbelievable! Same can happen with mutations?

Comment: yes, mutations additionally are processed sequentially